# Update TableView with Array data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview, viewdidload

I have a `PFQuery` in `viewDidLoad` called in `getUserPicPostData`. The output shows there are 3 images in the array count.

**ViewdidLoad:**

```
func getUserPicPostData() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "PicPost")
    query.whereKey("Username", equalTo: usernameSelected)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                self.picLikeArray.append(object["UserLikes"] as! Int)
                self.picTimeArray.append(object["UserTime"] as! String)
                self.picObjectIdArray.append(object.objectId!)

                let userImageFile = object["ImageFile"] as? PFFileObject

                userImageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.picPostArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!) 
                        print(self.picPostArray.count)
                    } 
                    else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            } 
        }
    })
}
```

Then I want to tell my cells to take the inputs of the imageArray. PicPostArray is now nil??

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
print(picPostArray)
cell.imageView1.imageView!.image = picPostArray[0]
cell.imageView2.imageView!.image = picPostArray[1]
cell.imageView3.imageView!.image = picPostArray[2]
```

Comment: where are you initialise the picObjectIdArray?

Comment: where are you calling tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Make sure your iterations are appending values to array correctly and you are reloading the tableview right after finishing all iterations.

Comment: im calling tableview reload in viewdidappear

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the table, your `picPostArray` is nil because it's not setted yet. This is due to your asynchronous `query.findObjectsInBackground`. To solve this, you can reload the table only when `picPostArray`is setted:

```
var picPostArray: [UIImage] = [] {
    didSet {
        yourTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i call this?

Comment: before `viewDidLoad`, where you create the variable, you add `didSet` like in the example above

Comment: hmm it's still displaying the index is out of range

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the tableView after adding the image on the list.

`picPostArray` initialization will be

```
var picPostArray:[UIImage] = [] // picPostArray not nil
```

And then reload the tableView when the image is set on the array.

```
self.picPostArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!) 
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Due to an asynchronous request, you need to reload the tableView.

Hope this will solve this issue.

Comment: i have other data that I reload in ViewdidAppear that isn't part of the tableView.

Comment: currently you can get the image data one by one. So you need to add tableView reload when an image is added on the list. TableView reload in ViewDidAppear is ok for an image. But the others images are loading asynchronous way. In this process image is added on the list but the tableview not show the image. You have to reload the tableview when an image is added on the list.